# Flume in EC2 and sink as HDFS in EMR. Is it possible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-ec2

I have a hadoop cluster in EMR and I have a EC2 instance. I need to install flume in EC2 node and use HDFS in EMR as sink. I have been trying this for sometime, but not being able to do so. I get the following exception:

```
 2017-12-19 10:50:32,428 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [WARN - org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.HDFSEventSink.process(HDFSEventSink.java:443)] HDFS IO error
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 3
     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:740)
     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:220)
     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:359)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.createRPCNamenode(DFSClient.java:106)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:207)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:170)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:82)
     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1378)
     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:66)
     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1390)
     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:196)
     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:175)
     at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$1.call(BucketWriter.java:260)
     at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$1.call(BucketWriter.java:252)
     at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$9$1.run(BucketWriter.java:701)
     at org.apache.flume.auth.SimpleAuthenticator.execute(SimpleAuthenticator.java:50)
     at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$9.call(BucketWriter.java:698)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Check whether the EC2 can access the EMR cluster. Enable the security rules. You need to add this in the EMR master and slave security groups. Use flume that is compatible with the hadoop in EMR

Comment: The EMR Master node is reachable from EC2 node

Comment: Hi, did you work it out?

Comment: @LucentXu Nope, didnt work